# How to drop duplicated rows using pandas in a big data file?

Tags: python, database, pandas, bigdata

I have a csv file that too big to load to memory.I need to drop duplicated rows of the file.So I follow this way:

```
chunker = pd.read_table(AUTHORS_PATH, names=['Author ID', 'Author name'],      encoding='utf-8', chunksize=10000000)

for chunk in chunker:
    chunk.drop_duplicates(['Author ID'])
```

But if duplicated rows distribute in different chunk seems like above script can't get the expected results.

Is there any better way？

Answer (score 3):

You could try something like this.

First, create your chunker.

```
chunker = pd.read_table(AUTHORS_PATH, names=['Author ID', 'Author name'], encoding='utf-8', chunksize=10000000)
```

Now create a set of ids:

```
ids = set()
```

Now iterate over the chunks:

```
for chunk in chunker:
    chunk.drop_duplicates(['Author ID'])
```

However, now, within the body of the loop, drop also ids already in the set of known ids:

```
    chunk = chunk[~chunk['Author ID'].isin(ids)]
```

Finally, still within the body of the loop, add the new ids

```
    ids.update(chunk['Author ID'].values)
```

---

If `ids` is too large to fit into main memory, you might need to use some disk-based database.

Comment: Thanks! I tried it,but the memory still not enough.

Comment: @yangxg Are you sure the set is the entity taking up your memory? What is its maximum `len`? If that is the problem, we need to escalate gradually. The next thing I would try is [`shelve`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/shelve.html).

Comment: would addthing something like this to the loop potentially help?  chunk['Author ID'] = pd.to_numeric(chunk['Author ID'], downcast='integer')